# Ubuntu wifi usually not working on boot, needs kernel module restart

Tags: boot, wireless, drivers, kernel, hardware

After installing Ubuntu on my netbook, an F205TA, wifi seems to be not working correctly. Usually wifi is not working after boot, but starts working after one or more tries of:

```
sudo modprobe -r brcmfmac
sudo modprobe brcmfmac
```

I have not had the chance to test on Windows, so I am not sure whether this is a driver issue or a hardware issue.

Edit:

[Wireless script output](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b6f0c685ecf84e901b88)

I have already tried searching, but did not find more information about this specific problem. I also do not know how to debug this issue further.

Second edit:

To install the wifi driver I installed the rtl8192cu-dkms package from [here](https://launchpad.net/~hanipouspilot/+archive/ubuntu/rtlwifi). I also followed the guide under "WiFi" from [here](https://wiki.debian.org/InstallingDebianOn/Asus/X205TA) to install firmware. There *might* also be some data remaining from some other attempts to get it working.

[/etc/fstab](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/af6d4564249c57d1d6a2)

Output of `grep -e '^/' /proc/mounts`: [gist](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/2fd509073074fff4c821).

Comment: Some more research and testing needed before posting it here

Comment: @Ashu, I do not know how to further research this issue, that's why I posted here. Could you give any help on what to do?

Comment: @DavidFoerster Thank you for your reaction, I added the output of the script to the question.

Comment: Good idea to include the diagnosis results of both states! How did you install the driver for the wireless adapter? Did you install the device firmware? If so, how? What's the partitioning scheme of your Ubuntu setup (include the content of `/etc/fstab` and output of `grep -e '^/' /proc/mounts`)?

Comment: @DavidFoerster, thanks again for your response. I added the information you requested.

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, the hardware is highly dependent on the system that supports it. I used a Lenovo notebook sometimes back it was highly incompatible with Linux distros. I tried Ubuntu, Linux Mint and some other distros as well. Each had some problems - one such in Ubuntu & Mint was the WiFi module, similar to what you are experiencing. Out of frustration I sold the laptop and purchased the one that supports the OS I'm supposed to use. Here is the list of supported hardware by Ubuntu and Linux Mint, you can google for the rest.

1. Ubuntu certified - https://certification.ubuntu.com
2. Linux Mint supported hardware - https://community.linuxmint.com/hardware

That's an advice and try whether the tidbits in [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/869454/389479) help you resolve the problem.

Comment: Just realised this is an old question ;) Anyway i hope it helps someone :)