# No sound on my Asus X205TA

Tags: sound, kernel, hardware, asus

I haven't any sound on my Asus X205TA after installation of Ubuntu 16.04.

Is there any way to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

There is no Linux sound support built into the vanilla or Ubuntu kernel for this device yet.

Thanks to a lot of hard work by many people, a kernel patch has been written for the sound card.

I recommend installing a pre-built kernel compiled by harryharryharry (updated since Meltdown & Spectre) as described [here on Ubuntu Forums](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254322&page=132&p=13595504#post13595504).

Download the kernel:

```
wget http://x205ta.myftp.org:1337/kernel/kernel-sound-64bit.tar
```

or if you have installed a 32-bit system

```
wget http://x205ta.myftp.org:1337/kernel/kernel-sound-32bit.tar
```

Run these commands to install

```
tar xf kernel-sound-64bit.tar 
sudo ./install-sound-kernel.sh -v
```

The script asks whether you want to reboot now or later. After rebooting, as the script tells you, you need to run `pavucontrol` or otherwise change the audio settings to set **Speaker** and not **Headphones** as the default soundcard output.

Otherwise, you need to compile the kernel yourself, using [harryharryharry's instructions](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2254322&page=158&p=13625163#post13625163) or [Lopaka's instructions](https://github.com/lopaka/instructions/blob/master/ubuntu-16.04-install-asus-x205ta.md) (see the sound section).

Comment: I confirm this is still working in May 2019. It now installs kernel 5.0.1 (-sound-41). The previous 4.16.13-sound-33 kernel had stopped working for me, but rerunning this script has fixed audio :)